# CMFCCaptionMenuButton alternative?

Tags: c++, mfc, button, menu

I need to create a caption bar button for a `CDockablePane` which will call up a menu with various options.  I tried to use `CMFCCaptionMenuButton` and the button and menu show up but the message map methods for the menu ids don't fire.  The MFC documentation states that `CMFCCaptionMenuButton` is meant for internal infrastructure and not really for your code.

So assuming that is what my problem is should I be using a `CMFCCaptionBarButton` and then making a separate popup menu?  Has anyone made a similar caption bar based menu in MFC before?

Here's some slimmed down code snippets in case I just made a stupid mistake in hooking up the events:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDockPane, CDockablePane)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_MORPH_BROWSER, OnMorphBrowser)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CDockPane::OnPressButtons(UINT nHit)
{
    // only for custom button handling don't call base
    // close, maximize, and pin will be handled by default

    switch (nHit)
    {
        case ID_MORPHTEST:
        {
            CMorphMenuButton* pButton = dynamic_cast<CMorphMenuButton*>(m_arrButtons.GetAt(m_morphIndex));
            pButton->ShowMenu(this);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void CDockPane::SetCaptionButtons()
{
    CDockablePane::SetCaptionButtons(); // for close, pin etc

    m_morphIndex = m_arrButtons.Add(new CMorphMenuButton(ID_MORPHTEST));
}

void CDockPane::OnMorphBrowser()
{
    // do stuff on menu item click
}
```

Edit: Removed previous code no longer in use

Comment: Surely this is doomed to failure when Aero/DWM is accounted for. It has a completely different implementation for the non-client area. I think you would have to have a totally different approach for Aero/DWM. Have you looked at Firefox or Chromium? They might give you some useful pointers.

Comment: @David What is Aero/DWM? This isn't a browser it's an MFC application targeted for Windows 7 64bit. Perhaps the callback name may have tripped you up that's specific to my implementation where a browser window is an itemized equipment list versus the 3d viewer window, hierarchical navigator, statistics dashboard, etc, etc

Comment: Aero is the marketing name for the new graphics frame work introduced in Vista. DWM is Desktop Window Manager, part of the same thing. It's the thing that handles the glass effects in non-client areas of windows.

Comment: Ah interesting well I don't have any code specifically related to that but I just tested the application with alt+tab and whether I have floating or docked panes it seems to behave properly at least as far as the glass effect goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the sound of crickets chirping has dwindled in the background I guess I'll post the workaround I currently have in place:

Instead of inheriting and extending `CMFCCaptionMenuButton` I build my class by extending `CMFCCaptionButton`.  I then create a menu and provide a ShowMenu method to be explicitly called when handling the custom button events as well as overriding GetIconID to return a particular system icon for the button for each menu added to the caption bar ending up with something like this for the example outlined in the question:

```
#pragma once

// CMorphMenuButton command target

class CMorphMenuButton : public CMFCCaptionButton
{
public:
    CMorphMenuButton(UINT nHit);
    virtual ~CMorphMenuButton();

    virtual CMenuImages::IMAGES_IDS GetIconID (BOOL bHorz, BOOL bMaximized) const;
    void ShowMenu(CWnd* pWnd);

private:
    CMenu m_dockMenu;
    CMenu* m_subMenu;
};

// MorphMenuButton.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MorphMenuButton.h"


// CMorphMenuButton
CMorphMenuButton::CMorphMenuButton(UINT nHit)
    : CMFCCaptionButton(nHit)
{
    SetMiniFrameButton(); // already defaulted?

    m_dockMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_DOCKPANE); // resource ID for dock pane menus
}

CMorphMenuButton::~CMorphMenuButton()
{
    m_dockMenu.DestroyMenu();
}

CMenuImages::IMAGES_IDS CMorphMenuButton::GetIconID(BOOL bHorz, BOOL bMaximized) const
{
    return CMenuImages::IdArrowForward;
}

void CMorphMenuButton::ShowMenu(CWnd* pWnd)
{
    CRect windowRect, buttonRect;
    pWnd->GetWindowRect(&windowRect);
    buttonRect = GetRect();
    CPoint menuPos(windowRect.left + buttonRect.right, windowRect.top + buttonRect.bottom);

    m_subMenu = m_dockMenu.GetSubMenu(0);
    if (!m_subMenu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, menuPos.x, menuPos.y, pWnd))
    {
        DWORD id = GetLastError();
        wchar_t errMsg[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, id, 0, errMsg, sizeof(errMsg), 0);
        MessageBox(0, errMsg, L"Error", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

The setting of caption bar buttons and handling of click events for both buttons and menus are the same as defined in the question and this works.